# Forward page request using JavaScript functions return values?

Tags: javascript

Here is the related part of code:

```
<form id="frmDemo" name="frmDemo" action="temp.jsp" method="post" > 
   <div>
        <hr/><a name="d2"></a>
        <h2>CMS Sign In Page</h2>
        <p>Passing parameters to the Web Service:</p> 
        <label>Your username: </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="elthefar" />

    <label>Your password: </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="workandwork" />
    <input type="button" value="Sign In" onclick="var r = SignIn(); if (r == 0) document.forms[0].action = 'temp2.jsp'; return true;" />
```

I want my form to forward to `temp2.jsp` if SignIn `return 0`, otherwise to `temp.jsp`. but the above code doesn't forward to any page.

Comment: What is this `SignIn()` method  for ??

Comment: Do you mean to use `submit` as the input type rather than `button`?

Comment: I think you need to add a submit button to your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `onsubmit` event to you form like this:

```
<form id="frmDemo" name="frmDemo" action="temp.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return myfunction();">
```

and then use a simple submit button in your form.

```
<input type='submit' value='Sign In' />
```

in this case, when you click on submit button, the function will fire and in that function you can do what ever you want to do like this:

```
<script language='javascript'>
function myfunction(){
var r = SignIn();
if(r == 0)
  document.forms[0].action = 'temp2.jsp';
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: since he had used it in his code, I assume it is a custom function which he already has in his code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use `input type="submit"`? Or call `document.forms[0].submit();`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to this

```
<form id="frmDemo" name="frmDemo" method="post">
```

And change  `button` to `submit`

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" onClick="Validate()" value="Submit" />
```

And use your `javaScript`

```
<script language='javascript'>
        function Validate(){
            var r = SignIn();  // assuming, you have some implementation for SignIn() method
            var frm = document.getElementById("frmDemo") || null;
            if(frm) {
                if(r != 0)
                {
                    frm.action = 'temp.jsp';
                }else{
                    frm.action = 'temp2.jsp';
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
```